Missing something in godot4 visual shader?
This shader changes the color of a texture, but is ignored in a 3D viewport. Or changes all the colors. In the shader, the final texture has the correct changed color. What is missing to make the final image appear as it does in the shader?
Godot 4.2.2 Stable

After trying to add colors, images, an multipliers to all points in the shader I am at a loss. Thanks to inevitable frustration I eventually went though values one by one seeing what changed. I'm clearly not grasping something.
